# how to store data after doing modification using sparql update with Fuseki server

Tags: java, sparql, jena, fuseki, tdb

I use fuseki server to query and update my RDF data , there are any methode do save those modifications ? should i use TDB dataset to save modifications ?
If yes there are  please any exepmle that it can help me ?
thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you not continuing with your previous question?! You got an answer there, so  what's wrong with it? You should comment on this answer if something is unclear and **not open a new question with the same topic**!

Comment: If you are running with an in-memory model and not TDB as backend, clearly have to write the data back to disk as any modification is done on the in-memory only.

Comment: thanks you for your answer , my question it's how to write the data back to disk?
it's possible to use fuseki as tdb backend  or i need to use another TDB to save data ?if yes how can connect my fuseki server to the my TDB ?

Comment: See the Fuseki documentation and the answer on the users@jena mailing list. NB answer come from volunteers so no need to ask again just a few hours later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fuseki docker container describes how to configure fuseki to persist values. Just take a look here, basically you have to store them in TDB (with not in memory option). [See the documentation of the docker container how to do it](https://hub.docker.com/r/stain/jena-fuseki/).